# Remove child nodes from XML

Tags: powershell

How to remove all "groups" from XML via PowerShell?
Current XML: https://pastebin.com/raw/1dPiBSDZ

I want to be like this

```xml
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

This code ofc doent help...

```
[xml]$XML = Get-Content -Path "C:\StartLayout.xml" -Encoding UTF8 -Force
$Groups = $XML.LayoutModificationTemplate.DefaultLayoutOverride.StartLayoutCollection.StartLayout.Group

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $xml.RemoveChild($Group)  
}

$XML.Save("C:\StartLayout.xml")
```

Comment: change `$xml.RemoveChild($Group)` into `$Group.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Group)`

Comment: Well.. you were almost there ;)

Comment: Despite I'm maintaning this: https://github.com/farag2/Windows-10-Sophia-Script
LOL